# using Parse.com javascript and keep getting 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, unauthorized

I'm doing the initialize as i'm supposed to, with the right keys etc.
Even when doing so right within the function that is later using Parse.Cloud.run, I still get 401 unauthorized.

Is there a way to see if the initialize worked properly? 
does it return any kind of response? error? if so, how do I go about seeing said response?
the initialize is currently simply:

```
Parse.initialize("appid", "javascript key"); (with the correct keys of course).
```

then I call a cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('testfunction', aUserObj, {
                success: function(result) {
                    supersonic.ui.dialog.alert(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    supersonic.ui.dialog.alert(error);
                }
            });
```

and the error is 401 unauthorized (which I also see in the javascript console as POST api.parse.com..... 401 unauthorized).

btw - using curl and rest api key I can make it work without a problem, so it's not an actual permissions issue as best I can tell.

Thanks.

Comment: While debugging this, though I couldn't find any actual errors, I did inspect the network in chrome and saw the api request to parse did not include any identification keys at all for some reason.
No idea why, even though the initialize was properly done. (in fact, when omitting the initialize as a test, I received an error saying it was missing and required before doing the Cloud.run).
So I just don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: BAHHHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
A whole day, wasted, because I failed to realize I was passing a string of the json data to the cloud function, instead of an object.
Excuse me while I go yell at myself in the mirror and eat some more ice-cream.
Stupid, stupid, stupid…

Comment: I"m having the exact same issue. Being a complete newbie to coding I don't entirely understand what you mean or how I can fix it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @nopro : Thanks. You should make this an answer. I just couldn't find the issue until I found your post. I also spent hours on this... 

@rashadb : The second argument of Parse Cloud function calls from the client must be a JSON object. We were passing a string representation of the object, and not the object itself. In other words, we were doing `Parse.Cloud.run('some function', JSON.stringify(our JSON object), success/error callbacks);` instead of passing `our JSON object` directly as the second argument. I hope this explanation is clear enough. Please say so if it is not. 

All the best!

Comment: @nopro You need to close this question. It's annoying to find unanswered questions that aren't really unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You are right @nopro

The problem is the parameter format which makes the whole request omit app and javascript key which results in 401 error.

Thank you

I was trying to call function like this:

```
              Parse.Cloud.run('sendMessage', message, {
                    success: function(success) {

                        $scope.isLoading = false;
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        $scope.isLoading = false;
                    }
                });
```

but I should have done it like this:

```
                Parse.Cloud.run('sendMessage', {"message":message.id}, {
                    success: function(success) {

                        $scope.isLoading = false;
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        $scope.isLoading = false;
                    }
                });
```